# Find commas in pattern

Tags: regex

I have file with rows like this:

```
"B4P(6-3,5)-VH(LF)(SN)",JST,2018+,34000,SMD
893D226X0016C8W,VISHAY,2018+,"30,000",SMD
BL-BUF1V4V-AT-L,FOXLINK,2018+,1890,CONN
"TLP721F(D4-GR,M,F)",NSC,2001+,114,AUCDIP-16
```

How can i find all commas inside quotes? For example, i need to find this:

```
"B4P(6-3 >>,<< 5)-VH(LF)(SN)",JST,2018+,34000,SMD
893D226X0016C8W,VISHAY,2018+,"30 >>,<< 000",SMD
BL-BUF1V4V-AT-L,FOXLINK,2018+,1890,CONN
"TLP721F(D4-GR >>,<< M >>,<< F)",NSC,2001+,114,AUCDIP-16
```

Now I can only find text in quotes, tell me how to select only commas from it, using one regular expression?

```
("(?:\[??[^\[]*?"))
```

[Regex101 - online regex editor and debugger](https://regex101.com/r/sE3adu/1/)

Comment: There is nothing after `this:` in your question. Was something deleted?

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: Your expression correctly identifies text in quotes that contains commas.  But what are you looking for exactly?  Surely you don't want just the comma characters??

Comment: sorry, was problem with post validation...

Comment: to: George M
Im sure, i want exactly the comma characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplistic solution that works with your example:

It match only quoted strings having one or more `,` inside.

```
grep '"[^,]*,[^"]*"'
```

Hope it works for you.

#### Explanation

`"[^,]*` match `"` and following non `,` chars

`,` match the first `,` char

`[^"]*"` match following non `"` till find the next`"`

[image]

Comment: I have 3 matches:

Match 1
Full match 0-23 "B4P(6-3,5)-VH(LF)(SN)"
Match 2
Full match 73-81 "30,000"
Match 3
Full match 126-146 "TLP721F(D4-GR,M,F)"

But i need matches only commas:

Match 1
Full match ,
Match 2
Full match ,
Match 3
Full match ,

....

Comment: Please explain in the question the aim of your pattern match. I do not understand if you want to match only single comma inside quotes or more (can be done as well). The pattern match is a boolean operation per record (a line in your case), returning true or false. RegEx matching is a kind of filter. The provided regex fulfill your request and identify all quoted text having one or more comma. If you want to use a regex for comma replacement/extraction/marking operation (very legitimate) please state that in the question, state the tools you are using.

Comment: I wanna to match all commas inside quotes... and only commas, not text

Comment: And Yes, i want to use a regex for comma replacement/extraction/marking operation 
 using notedepad++ for example...